# Deploy PHP application into Flynn

Tags: php, composer-php, craftcms, flynn

I'm trying to install Craft CMS (https://github.com/craftcms/cms/tree/3.5) on Flynn running through [Vagrant](https://flynn.io/docs/installation/vagrant).

When I try to push it via Flynn CLI it throws an error:

```
PS D:\cms> git push flynn 3.5
Logon failed, use ctrl+c to cancel basic credential prompt.
Enumerating objects: 293867, done.
Counting objects: 100% (293867/293867), done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (61947/61947), done.
Writing objects: 100% (293867/293867), 162.26 MiB | 3.23 MiB/s, done.
Total 293867 (delta 224740), reused 293867 (delta 224740), pack-reused 0
remote: The push must include a change to the master branch to be deployed.
To https://git.demo.localflynn.com/cms.git
 ! [remote rejected]       3.5 -> 3.5 (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.demo.localflynn.com/cms.git'
```

How can I deploy Craft CMS as an application on Flynn?

Answer (score 2):

The error is:

```
remote: The push must include a change to the master branch to be deployed.
```

So to resolve this issue, push your branch to the master branch in the remote:

```
git push flynn 3.5:master
```

Comment: Maybe you can also help with: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62861547/bootstrap-flynn-inside-a-virtual-machine

Comment: Is there a way to deploy Flynn on a single Virtual Machine instance?